# Iterate between two python dictionaries and be able to "increment" to the next string index separately

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to learn python so I don't even know if there's a feature for this. but lets say I have the following two dictionaries

```
dict1 = {
   'key1': 1
   'key2': 2
   'key3': 3
}

dict2 = {
   'key1': 0
   'key2': 2
   'key3': 4
}
```

Now I want to iterate between the two dictionaries but if one of the keys' value is 0, I want the other dictionary to move to the next string index. You can assume both dictionaries have the same number of keys and key names.

Basically I want something like this:

```
for someKey, anotherKey in dict1, dict2:
   if dict1[someKey] == 0:
        #Move someKey to the next string index
        #In other words move someKey from 'key1' -> 'key2' (On loop 0)
   if dict2[anotherKey] == 0:
        #Move anotherKey to the next string index
        #In other words move someKey from 'key1' -> 'key2' (On loop 0)
```

Was looking into zip, but I don't think it solves the problem of maintaining separate string indices

So example output would be like:

```
(loop 1)
1 == 0? no 
0 == 0? yes
   Now only move anotherKey from 'key1' to 'key2'

(loop 2)
1 == 0? no
2 == 0? no

Now here it would infinitely loop here, but I have some code 
that does some dice rolling and decrements one of the 
values so it guarantees one number will eventually be 0. 
Just keep that in mind.
```

Comment: What does it mean to "Move key1 to the next string index"

Comment: Could you give some sample input / output? As it currently stands, what you're describing would infinitely loop upon both dictionaries being at a nonzero value, which I don't think is what you're looking for.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I updated the question so maybe it clarifies a bit more?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I updated the question so maybe it clarifies a bit more? Don't know how to @ multiple people lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a "pythonistic" way to solve it. Instead, you can try an approach more "algorithmic" using `while`:

```
keys1 = list(dict1.keys())
keys2 = list(dict2.keys())
i = j = 0

while i < len(keys1) and j < len(keys2):      
   if dict1[keys1[i]] == 0:
        i += 1
   if dict2[keys2[j]] == 0:
        j += 1
```

I think may be there is another solution but this is practical.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using iterators. See `iter()` and `next()`, both Python built-in functions documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) for some background.

```py
dict1 = {
   'key1': 1,
   'key2': 2,
   'key3': 3
}

dict2 = {
   'key1': 0,
   'key2': 2,
   'key3': 4
}

it1 = iter(dict1)
it2 = iter(dict2)
v1 = next(it1, None)
v2 = next(it2, None)
count = 0
while v1 is not None or v2 is not None:
    print(f"v1, dict1[v1] {v1, dict1[v1] if v1 is not None else 'na'}, v2, dict2[v2] {v2, dict2[v2] if v2 is not None else 'na'}")
    if v1 is not None and dict1[v1] == 0:
        v1 = next(it1, None)
    if v2 is not None and dict2[v2] == 0:
        v2 = next(it2, None)
    # simulate dice rolling and decrement mentioned in the question
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        dict1['key1'] = 0
    elif count == 6:
        dict2['key2'] = 0
    elif count == 9:
        dict1['key2'] = 0
        dict2['key3'] = 0
    elif count == 12:
        dict1['key3'] = 0
print(f"v1, dict1[v1] {v1, dict1[v1] if v1 is not None else 'na'}, v2, dict2[v2] {v2, dict2[v2] if v2 is not None else 'na'}")
```

Output:

```
v1, dict1[v1] ('key1', 1), v2, dict2[v2] ('key1', 0)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key1', 1), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 2)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key1', 1), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 2)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key1', 0), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 2)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 2), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 2)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 2), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 2)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 2), v2, dict2[v2] ('key2', 0)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 2), v2, dict2[v2] ('key3', 4)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 2), v2, dict2[v2] ('key3', 4)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key2', 0), v2, dict2[v2] ('key3', 0)
v1, dict1[v1] ('key3', 3), v2, dict2[v2] (None, 'na')
v1, dict1[v1] ('key3', 3), v2, dict2[v2] (None, 'na')
v1, dict1[v1] ('key3', 0), v2, dict2[v2] (None, 'na')
v1, dict1[v1] (None, 'na'), v2, dict2[v2] (None, 'na')
```